# Filter databound combobox based on value in another column from the same dataset

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am attempting to create a process scheduler as a project in school this summer and am quite new to using VB.  Currently I have a combobox bound to the "EmployeeBindingSource" which holds information for every single employee in a company.  Each employee is assigned a skill level for each work station in the building.  What I would like to do is if an employee is listed as having "0" skill in say, the assembly station, when selecting an employee to assign to the assembly station, that particular employee will not appear in the combobox.

From doing some research I believe that rather than binding the combobox to the data source in the designer, I will have to assign values to the each combo box in the code on a form load.

[This is the access table that holds all the employee information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk9Lk.jpg)

In the table we can see that Steve has a skill level of "0" in the AS_Level category (assembly).

[However, here we can see that he still appears as an option for the assembly area when creating a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufgTY.jpg)

Currently all the data binding happens in the designer for each combo box and therefore no code has been written for the data binding. At the moment each combo box is bound to the "Full_Name" column in the access table.

Again, I am quite new to VB so I apologize if this is too vague.  Let me know if I can give any more helpful information.  Thank you all in advance.

After adding the code suggested here is what I have

```
  provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    datafile = "C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop\Halton\HaltonProject.accdb"
    connString = provider & datafile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE (SP_Level <> '" & 0 & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

    Dim userfound As Boolean = False
    Dim Full_Name As String

    While dr.Read
        userfound = True
        Full_Name = dr("Full_Name").ToString
        SP_Emp1.Items.Add(Full_Name)
        SP_Emp2.Items.Add(Full_Name)
        SP_Emp3.Items.Add(Full_Name)
        SP_Emp4.Items.Add(Full_Name)
    End While

    myConnection.Close()
```

Works completely now!

Comment: could you post your binding code, it will be helpful. If you're binding each combo box individually, you could add a where clause to get the info from the table where "x" parameter is not 0

Comment: Currently for binding all I am doing is assigning the binding for each combobox in the designer itself by clicking the little carrot in the top right corner and choosing the data source, display member, and value member.  For data source I'm using the "EmployeeBindingSource" which is the access table shown, and for both display member and value member I am using "Full_Name."  Would something like this be the correct path? `Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE **code here** , myConnection)
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and post, I assume, the checkboxes on the left enable/disable the comboboxes on that row, and since you're binding them individually if you change your query so it looks like this:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE AS_Level <> 0 , myConnection) Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Note that the where clause will vary depending on your needs, so it could be `WHERE AS_Level <> 0` or `WHERE SP_Level <> 0` and so on.

I have never used an Ole database so I'm not quite sure about the syntax, hope this helps.

Comment: Yes the checkboxes function in this way.  I believe this to be the correct path, but I am also unsure of the syntax.  This does certainly help though, thank you!

Comment: I have updated the original post with the code I am using now that mirrors your suggestion.  Only a small issue remains which I have also explained in the OP

Comment: sorry but, what is the other issue that you have?? Maybe I'm not understanding the question itself lol, is it about the binding??

Comment: It is fixed, I just needed to move the part where I add the items manually to the combobox into the while loop as opposed to having it in its own for loop.  Thank you for all your help!